# US Xbox 360 to Ireland

Tags: ireland, power

I recently came to Ireland and brought my Xbox with me. I bought an adapter for it but I'm not sure it will work with the Xbox or fry the power brick. [Here](http://www.harveynorman.ie/computing/apple/apple-accessories/cables-and-adaptors/kensington-international-travel-adapter-k38120ww.html) is the link.

Comment: What does the power supply provided with your Xbox say in terms of input voltage and frequency? Nowadays most devices ship with universal power supplies (110-240V), but there are exceptions, and according to the link provided by [Phil](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/62780/30703) the Xbox 360 is one of those. If the power supply is 110-127V, then that adapter (which only handles the differing plugs, but doe nothing for voltage or frequency) will definitely not be suitable.

Comment: Laptops and the like tend to come with universal adaptors; game consoles seem to be an exception - likely because they're already tied to location due to dependencies on the display output (PAL vs NTSC - though this is less of an issue these days with HDMI) and on use of region-coded media.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is not compatible.  Ireland uses the European standard of 230volts (or 240v) 50Hertz.  The US uses 120v 60Hz.  Looking at http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/console/power-supply it looks like the xboxes ship with a different external PSU for each area.  If you plug a 100v PSU into 240V power it's likely to blow up.  Your best bet is to buy a new external powersupply.

Comment: US uses 120V, It is Japan that uses 100V

Comment: Hmmm, not sure where the 100v came from, I've fixed it, thanks @RedGrittyBrick